# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am getting the below error while starting a windows service based on .net framework 5

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
    File name: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0
```

I have tried the below methods. But it is not resolved

- Registered the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll into GAC
- Enabled "Auto-generate binding redirects" on the referenced project files

Comment: You should not be registering NuGet assembles into the GAC - that might be the _cause_ of the issue.

Comment: Please post the exception's `FusionLog`.

Comment: @Dai It was not registered. I tried to check whether it will resolve the issue. But didn't work.

Comment: "It was not registered" <-- _that's the point_. We should not be using the GAC for assemblies anymore.

Comment: @Dai It wasn't working even without registering